# How does an operator inside a class work?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operators

```
class A {
public:
    string operator+( const A& rhs ) {
        return "this and A&";
    }
};

string operator+( const A& lhs, const A& rhs ) {
    return "A& and A&";
}

string operator-( const A& lhs, const A& rhs ) {
    return "A& and A&";
}

int main() {
    A a;
    cout << "a+a = " << a + a << endl;
    cout << "a-a = " << a - a << endl;
    return 0;
}

//output
a+a = this and A&
a-a = A& and A&
```

I'm curious as to why the operator inside the class gets to be called rather than the outside one. Is there some sort of priority among operators?

Comment: The process of selecting amongst several functions of the same name is called *overload resolution*.  In this code, the member is preferred because the non-member requires a qualification conversion (adding `const` to `lhs`) but the member does not. If you made the member function `const` (which you should, since it does not modify `*this`) then it would be ambiguous

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The process of selecting amongst several functions of the same name is called *overload resolution*. In this code, the member is preferred because the non-member requires a qualification conversion (adding `const` to `lhs`) but the member does not. If you made the member function `const` (which you should, since it does not modify `*this`) then it would be ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever your object is non-const there's a priority of non-constness over constness. The inner will be called when the left side is non-const, and the outer will be called when the left side is const.

See what happens when the inner is defined as:

`string operator+( const A& rhs ) const;`

Comment: "There's a priority of non-constness over constness." Not in the general case. If `a` had been declared as `const A a;`, the out-of-class overload would be used.

Comment: That's what I wrote.

Comment: The way the answer's written, "there's a priority of non-constness over constness" sounds like a general statement. Which would of course be incorrect.